# SVG xlink:href path to .jpg not working (inside my website project)

Tags: svg, xlink

Why, when I open my .svg file alone in the browser it **does** show the picture from **xlink:href** but inside my website project it **does not show** the picture from **xlink:href**?

This is the image from **xlink:href** --> https://s10.postimg.org/ky5y39vvd/Untitled-19.png

Inside my website project I use either img tag or background-image to link to my .svg file...

The point is I want .svg file to work inside my website project :)

This is my SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
    <title>Text Pattern Fill Example</title>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="120" height="140">
            <image xlink:href="https://s10.postimg.org/e2h45vefd/alex-iby.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="300"
             transform="translate(135.780723, 50.780723) rotate(90.000000) translate(-55.780723, -60.780723)"
             /><!-- Image from http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile/6-grass-meadow-tile.php-->
        </pattern>
    </defs>

        <path d="M59.2078786,111.129597 C101.335439,132.142715 115.952158,85.5158857 115.952158,53.9197716 C115.952158,22.3236576 102.07475,5.17108475 70.7357496,5.17108475 C39.3967496,5.17108475 13.4042112,19.8971044 -0.939389391,40.9853457 C-15.28299,62.0735871 17.0803178,90.1164792 59.2078786,111.129597 Z"  transform="translate(55.780723, 60.780723) rotate(-90.000000) translate(-55.780723, -60.780723) " fill="url(#img1)"></path>        
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue relates to security rules that prevent loading external urls from a different domain. If you would load that raster image from "within" your web-site - it would be allowed by browsers.

But this will work from your localhost which is allowed in browsers.

See this article for related context: https://medium.com/the-ui-files/load-svgs-from-different-domains-ports-protocols-1614e1af6101